# How can I use third party class in EE to render instagram images on templates?

Tags: add-on-development, php, plugin, custom-classes

I have been using an instagram class in projects for Laravel and other small php sites and it has seemed to work well. I include a require_once in my functions file. I then create a function that calls the instagram class and then in my template I call the function and it works.

This is the instagram class on github: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Heres a simple example on a recent wp site I did:

## The function

```
require_once('includes/instagram.class.php');

function get_instagram_image() {

    $instagram = new Instagram('253daacbd2b849dd9d1255ecf26088b7');
    $name = 'Ahastag';
    $result = $instagram->getTagMedia($name);

    foreach ($result->data as $media) {
            $content = "<li class='col5-1'>";

            // output media
            if ($media->type === 'video') {
              // video
              $poster = $media->images->standard_resolution->url;
              $source = $media->videos->standard_resolution->url;
              $content .= "<video class=\"media video-js vjs-default-skin\" width=\"250\" height=\"250\" poster=\"{$poster}\"
                           data-setup='{\"controls\":true, \"preload\": \"auto\"}'>
                             <source src=\"{$source}\" type=\"video/mp4\" />
                           </video>";
            } else {
              // image
              $image = $media->images->standard_resolution->url;
              $content .= "<img class=\"media\" src=\"{$image}\"/>";
            }

            // create meta section
            $avatar = $media->user->profile_picture;
            $username = $media->user->username;
            $comment = $media->caption->text;
            $content .= "<div class=\"content\">
                           <div class=\"avatar\" style=\"background-image: url({$avatar})\"></div>
                           <h3>{$username}</h3>
                           <div class=\"comment\"><p>{$comment}</p></div>
                         </div>";

            // output media
            echo $content . "</li>";
          }

}
```

## What I used in the template

```
<?php get_instagram_image(); ?>
```

Now I am trying to do the same in Expression Engine. I am aware of libraries/addons etc but I am struggling to keep it as simple as I have done in WP above and I am sure it can be as its only a php script at the end of the day.

What I want to do is either create a plugin or new ee class that does exactly what I have done above but in my ee templates and frontend.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I want to develop my own and not use one already out there because I want to keep as clean as possible and not overly bloated and complex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you have there you can *almost* just wrap in a plugin. [Start by reading the plugin development docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/plugins.html).

However, you can probably simplify your code - and make it more flexible - by instead of building your output markup inside of the plugin, populating an array of data, then returning it to the template, where you use EE variables to create your markup.

[Read the docs on the Template class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html) for an overview of how this works.

Here's a real quick bit of code as an example:

```
$vars = array();
foreach ($result->data as $media)
{
    $vars[] = array(
        'type' => $media->type,
        'image' => $media->images->standard_resolution->url,
        'video' => $media->videos->standard_resolution->url,
        'avatar' => $media->user->profile_picture,
        'username' => $media->user->username,
        'comment' => $media->caption->text
    );
}
return ee()->TMPL->parse_variables(ee()->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
```

Then you can use this in your template:

```
{exp:my_plugin:instagram_image}
    {if type == 'video'}
        // build your video embed using the above variables ({source}, {image}, etc)
    {/if}
    {if type == 'image'}
        <img src="{image}" alt="{caption}" />
    {/if}
{/exp:my_plugin:instagram_image}
```